# Different expressions for an integral if I split the region of integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions, piecewise

Consider the assumptions

```
$Assumptions = 1 > v > 0 && y1 \[Element] Reals && y2 \[Element] Reals &&   k > 0 && 1 > t1 > 0
```

and define

```
y[t_, y1_, y2_, t1_] = 
      Piecewise[{{y1, 0 <= t <= t1}, {y2, t1 < t <= 1}}, 0];
```

and two different formulations of the same integral,

```
Assuming[t1 + v < 1, 
  Integrate[
   Assuming[{0 <= t <= 1, t1 + v < 1}, 
    Integrate[(1 + 
        Exp[-2 Integrate[y[s, y1, y2, t1]^2, {s, t - u - v, t - v}]])/
      2, {u, 0, t}]], {t, v, t1 + v}]] // Simplify
```

and

```
Assuming[t1 + v < 1, 
   Integrate[
    Assuming[{0 <= t <= 1, t1 + v < 1}, 
     Integrate[(1 + 
         Exp[-2 Integrate[
            y[s, y1, y2, t1]^2, {s, t - u - v, t - v}]])/2, {u, 0, 
       t - v}]], {t, v, t1 + v}]] + 
  Assuming[t1 + v < 1, 
   Integrate[
    Assuming[{0 <= t <= 1, t1 + v < 1}, 
     Integrate[(1 + 
         Exp[-2 Integrate[
            y[s, y1, y2, t1]^2, {s, t - u - v, t - v}]])/2, {u, t - v,
        t}]], {t, v, t1 + v}]] // Simplify
```

The two formulations differ for the region of integration, that in the second case is splitted in two parts, because the interval in u between 0 and t is splitted in [0,t-v]+[t-v,t],and then the integrals summed. Why Mathematica give me back two different expressions?

Comment: Why all those separate `Assuming` functions? Can't you combine them?

Comment: The `D` you use as a variable is a reserved word.

Comment: I combine a bit `Assuming`. I changed the variable from D to u (in my code I use greek symbols, but to be more clear I changed in D the variable symbol without checking). Also I've added some necessary $Assumptions. The main point is still there.

Comment: You have a `k>0` which seems not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the answer you're looking for.
It took a long time to run your code as it is so I changed it a bit.
The bottom line is that *Mathematica* is doing fine and the two expressions you get just look different.

Some definitions :

```
myAssum = 1 > v > 0 && y1 \[Element] Reals && y2 \[Element] Reals && 1 > t1 > 0
myConditions = {tMv -> t - v};
```

because until the last integration everything depends on `t-v` only, so no point carrying two variables.

```
intY2 = Simplify[Integrate[PiecewiseExpand[y[s, y1, y2, t1]^2], {s, tMv - u, tMv}, 
                 Assumptions -> {0 <= tMv <= t1, 0 <= u <= t}], 
        Assumptions -> {myAssum, 0 <= tMv <= t1, 0 <= u <= t}];

intExp = Integrate[(1 + Exp[-2 intY2])/2, {u, 0, t},  
                   Assumptions -> {0 <= tMv <= t1, 0 <= t <= 2}];
```

Now we substitute back `tMv -> t-v` and do the last integration :

```
result = Integrate[intExp /. myConditions, {t, v, t1 + v}, 
                   Assumptions -> myAssum];
```

To check the other approach I just repeat the last two steps :

```
intExp1 = Integrate[(1 + Exp[-2 intY2])/2, {u, 0, tMv},  
                    Assumptions -> {0 <= tMv <= t1, 0 <= t <= 2}];
intExp2 = Integrate[(1 + Exp[-2 intY2])/2, {u, tMv, t},  
                    Assumptions -> {0 <= tMv <= t1, 0 <= t <= 2}];

result1 = Integrate[intExp1 /. myConditions, {t, v, t1 + v}, 
                    Assumptions -> myAssum];
result2 = Integrate[intExp2 /. myConditions, {t, v, t1 + v}, 
                    Assumptions -> myAssum];
```

Check :

```
(result == result1 + result2 ) // Simplify
(* True *)
```